# Calculate sum of column for selected Ids in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-scripts

These are my tables:

- **Member**: `Id, Points`
- **CartRegister** : `Id, Member_Id, CartId, RegisterDate, Point`
- **SelectetMembers**: `Id, Member_Id`

Members can register Cart in `CartRegister`, and in `Member.Points` All points that a member earned must be calculated and inserted. So I need calculate all points of each `SelectedMembers` and update the `Member` table, but I don't know how to implement it.

The following script is in my head:

```
UPDATE [Member]
   SET [Points]=
    (
       SELECT SUM([CR].[Point]) AS [AllPoints]
       FROM  [CartRegister] AS [CR] 
       WHERE [CR].[Member_Id] = --???

    )
    WHERE [Members].[Member].[Id] IN  ( SELECT Member_Id From SelectedMembers  )
```

So I am confused to what is the where clause in `Select Sum(Point)` if I use

```
        WHERE [CR].[Member_Id] IN ( Select Member_Id From SelectedMembers  )
```

Then the sum of all members be same of sum of all Members Point, maybe I need something like `foreach` What is your suggestion?

Comment: I believe it should be `WHERE [CR].[Member_Id] = [Member].Id`.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović Thanks your answer is correct can you write it as an Answer, and I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
UPDATE [Member]
SET [Points]=
(
   SELECT SUM([CR].[Point]) AS [AllPoints]
   FROM  [CartRegister] AS [CR] 
   WHERE [CR].[Member_Id] = [Member].[Id]

)
WHERE [Members].[Member].[Id] IN  ( SELECT Member_Id From SelectedMembers  )
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use a CTE (Common Table Expression) to first calculate the points for each member, and then use that inforation to update the `Members` table:

```
-- this CTE takes all selected members, and calculates their total of points
;WITH MemberPoints AS
(
   SELECT 
       Member_ID,
       AllPoints = SUM(Point)
   FROM  
       CartRegister
   WHERE
       Member_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM SelectedMembers)
   GROUP BY 
       Member_ID
)
UPDATE dbo.Member  
SET Points = mp.AllPoints
FROM MemberPoints mp
WHERE dbo.Member.Member_ID = mp.Member_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on [@marc_s's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278924/calculate-sum-of-column-for-selected-ids-in-sql/10279019#10279019), which is basically the same, only uses a slightly different syntax:

```
WITH aggregated AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    AllPoints = SUM(Point) OVER (PARTITION BY Member_ID)
  FROM CartRegister
  WHERE Member_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM SelectedMembers)
)
UPDATE aggregated
SET Points = AllPoints
```